# Currency conversion - actual and latest available date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL problem that I am unable to solve so any help would be most appreciated. I am creating a database that tracks jobs in different currencies for a company. I have daily reported jobs and monthly currency conversion, which works fine. My problem is anticipated future billing dates, for those I need to use the latest available exchange rate. How can I write an SQL so that whenever then billing date is in the future it picks the latest available otherwise it takes the correct month? I have tried using both CASE and subqueries but havent been able to find a solution. Im using MS Access for this job.

My current SQL that works but fails to pickup future dates because of the inner join looks as follows

```
SELECT jobs.ProjectName, jobs.[NetFee]*Exch.[CurrencyRate] AS 
FROM tblJobs AS Jobs 
INNER JOIN tblExchangeRate AS Exch
ON Jobs.CurrencyID = Exch.CurrencyID
AND Year(Jobs.[BillDate]) = Year(Exch.[CurrencyDate])
AND Month(Jobs.[BillDate]) = Year(Exch.[CurrencyDate]);
```

The involved fields and tables have the following structure

tblExchangeRate (monthly data)

```
ID    CurrencyID    ExchangeRate    CurrencyDate
1     1             1.50            2005-01-31
2     1             1.52            2005-02-28
.
.
x     x             1.63            2014-08-30
```

tblJobs

```
ID    ProjectName    NetFee    CurrencyID    BillDate
1     AA             100       1             2010-01-15
2     BB             200       2             2015-04-20
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'I have tried using ... `CASE` ... I'm using MS Access for this job.' Hmm, if it's Access 'all the way down' then part of your problem is that Access SQL doesn't support `CASE` (it has `IIF`). That said, how about this:

```
SELECT jobs.ProjectName, jobs.NetFee * IIF(Exch.CurrencyRate Is Null,
                         LatestExch.CurrencyRate, Exch.CurrencyRate) AS M
FROM (tblJobs AS Jobs 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT lcr.CurrencyID, lcr.CurrencyRate
    FROM tblExchangeRate lcr
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT lcd.CurrencyID, MAX(lcd.CurrencyDate) AS CurrencyDate
        FROM tblExchangeRate AS lcd
        GROUP BY lcd.CurrencyID) AS lcd
    ON lcr.CurrencyID = lcd.CurrencyID AND lcr.CurrencyDate = lcd.CurrencyDate) AS LatestExch
ON Jobs.CurrencyID = LatestExch.CurrencyID )
LEFT JOIN tblExchangeRate AS Exch
ON Jobs.CurrencyID = Exch.CurrencyID
AND Year(Jobs.[BillDate]) = Year(Exch.[CurrencyDate])
AND Month(Jobs.[BillDate]) = Year(Exch.[CurrencyDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**first Query** 
 for the projects that its billing date   **not in the future** 
 in this query we get the ExchangeRate from the correct month in tblExchangeRate .

**second Query**
 for the projects that its billing date **in the future** 
in this query we get the ExchangeRate from the MaxExch (subquery) .

( MaxExch: subquery that select the latest ExchangeRate for every CurrencyID .)


***Solution*** : *first Query* **Union** secondQuery

```
(SELECT jobs.ProjectName AS PN, jobs.[NetFee]*Exch.[ExchangeRate] AS M
FROM tblJobs AS Jobs , tblExchangeRate AS Exch
WHERHE Jobs.CurrencyID = Exch.CurrencyID
       AND Year(Jobs.[BillDate]) = Year(Exch.[CurrencyDate])
       AND Month(Jobs.[BillDate]) = Year(Exch.[CurrencyDate])
)
UNION
(SELECT jobs.ProjectName AS PN, jobs.[NetFee]*MaxExch.[ExchangeRate] AS M
 FROM tblJobs AS Jobs , (SELECT CurrencyID, ExchangeRate, CurrencyDate
                         FROM tblJobs tb1
                         WHERE CurrencyDate = (SELECT MAX(CurrencyDate) FROM tblJobs t2
                                               WHERE t2.CurrencyID =t1.CurrencyID )
                         ) MaxExch
 WHERE Jobs.BillDate > MaxExch.CurrencyDate AND Jobs.CurrencyID= MaxExch.CurrencyID);
```